# Unable to fetch fiat account for coinbase transfers

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm trying to initiate withdrawals and deposits but the USD cash account is no longer listed in get accounts results or even when I follow the resource link from the results of payment methods to the fiat resource. I'm able to access the account through my dashboard but when I try to fetch it using the account id from expand resource, it gives me `Account not found` error.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue
I believe this is because when I user grant access through https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize they have to choose a single crypto account. Then when you list payment methods you get a fiat_account. This is both a payment_method and a fiat_account. However you can't access this account with your token which only works for the crypto account.
Have you found a turn arround ?
I was thinking of asking the user to grant access to a crypto account and their fiat account but didn't found a way to do it.

Comment: just found our answer : you need to request the user to grant you access to all of their accounts by adding the optional account parameter to your call with the value all
e.g. https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=***&redirect_uri=***&scope=wallet:accounts:read,wallet:payment-methods:read&account=all

Comment: @NicolasN where did you find that information?

Comment: OK found it here: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/permissions